# bringing Rand monad out of a `data` construct?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm using `Control.Monad.Rand`, and I have a structure

```
data MCSystem = MCSystem { params :: Params
                         , path   :: Path   }
```

And functions, which I don't know how to implement --

```
runSystem :: (RandomGen g) => MCSystem -> Rand g MCSystem
runSystem system = MCSystem mcparams newPath -- this line doesn't make any
                                             --   sense and i know it
  where
    mcparams = params system
    newPath  = runPath $ path system

runPath :: (RandomGen g) => Path -> Rand g Path
-- basically performs a random mutation on the path
```

`runPath` returns a `Rand g Path` monad ... how do I pull that to make a new `Rand g MCSystem` monad so `runSystem` can return it properly, and it can be called later with a generator?

I think maybe I can refactor everything into a Reader monad but I feel like I want to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Rand` is an instance of Monad, and can be used in all the ways a monad can. Just like any other monad, you "get the value" out, and operate on it using `>>=`.

For example, this works for the definition of runSystem:

```
runSystem system = runPath (path system) >>= \newPath -> return (MCSystem (params system) newPath)
```

The do syntax makes it nicer:

```
runSystem system = do 
  newPath <- runPath (path system)
  return $ MCSystem (params system) newPath
```

The best way though to use `Rand` applicative instance:

```
runSystem system = MCSystem <$> pure (params system) <*> runPath (path system)
```

However, if you haven't learnt about the applicative class yet, that may not make much sense (the other solutions are fine if that is the case).

Edit: Actually, all you really need is the `Functor` typeclass, so this also works, and is the best you can get:

```
runSystem system = MCSystem (params system) <$> runPath (path system)
```

Basically you are wrapping the result of `runPath (path system)` around a `MCSystem`

Comment: I feel kind of silly, I actually used the do notation approach in another part of the program, but in this case I was "refactoring" to add in randomness and was so blinded by the functional style I had already written it in.

Comment: In a way though, Applicative style seems more expressive. Do you have any good references to starting to program applicatively?

Comment: A good guide is the [Functors, Applicative Functors and Monoids chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) in the learn you a haskell tutorial.